# Google Appengine Old Blob File Service-- do we still have more time until we have to convert our code

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have a Google Appengine application that 
uses the Blobservice being deprecated.  Google
sent us an electronic mail saying that the 
service will be deleted July 28th.  It also
says May 20th "no new applicaitons
will have access to the Files API."

Our application (on June Second) received
an error message from the lines in our 
application:

```
final FileService fileservice = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
file = fileservice.createNewBlobFile("text/xml");

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'file' or call 'Create()' was not found.
    ...

at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:590)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:512)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewBlobFile(FileServiceImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewBlobFile(FileServiceImpl.java:93)
```

Has Google removed this capability earlier than I was expecting or 
have we misunderstood what
the Exceptions are trying to tell us?  I thought we had more time
to do the conversion.

(We have recently uploaded to a project created some time ago.  It 
appears the capability is working on uthreee.appspot.com.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a couple of applications of mine, which I solved opening a ticket to the support.

My application has been erroneously marked as "new application" (even if is very old) and because of that the Files API has been shutted down.

You need to open a support ticket providing the application ID, the eng. team will proceed to re-enable the Files API